# How do I set windows 7 to require password after I leave the computer for 5 minutes?

Tags: windows-7

I do not want my computer to sleep.

I want my computer to require password.

Should be simple enough.

If I switch user, users would need to enter password to access my computer.

What about if I just left the computer?

I do not want autosleep. My computer is doing productive stuff when I am out.

Comment: This can be helped by a group policy. You should also be able to just enable a screensaver http://www.it.cornell.edu/security/howto/screenlockhowwin.cfm and if you are wondering the downvote is for the lack of information about your configuration and the fact this is a well documented topic indicating you didn't do enough research.

Comment: Note you can lock your computer instantly via pressing the Windows Key + `L`

Comment: I know I can lock my computer instantly. I often forget.

Comment: Okay, it's well documented. Say I want to find it in google, what keyword should I search? Not screen saver. I don't know that I have to use that feature. I search for windows 7 switch user and got nothing.

Comment: @JimThio - What exactly is wrong with the screensaver solution? If you don't want a screensaver it requires you to use the group policy method. As for a research term "auto lock Windows 7" is a valid search term.  **On a side note your own search term came with similar results.**

Comment: I thought they talk about making the computer sleep, not making the computer switch user

Comment: Actually, what I find is this http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/39749-how-set-automatically-switch-user.html the answer there says it's not possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open the Start Menu → Type "Screen Saver" → Click "change screen saver".
2. Choose "Wait 5 minutes", Check `On Resume, display logon screen`.
3. Press OK.

This will lock your computer after you are away for 5 minutes. You will need to type your password to access your desktop again, your programs will continue running.

You can also lock your computer immediately by pressing Win+L.

[image: duh]